# How can I make desktop application for single user?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created one of the software for one organization. But there is also threat of software piracy. I want to be keep(install) this on only one computer.As per my perception i will be 
 creating web service which will invoked at the time of installation and will collect the system info and restrict further processing if it is already exists in the database. This is my assumption and thought that i would go through, Is there any other way to achieve this or is there built in functionality to overcome this.

Any responses are appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: The more time you spend making it difficult for your legitimate customers to use your software, the less time you're spending on features that the customers perceive as valuable, and, the more likely they are to seek out illegitimate copies of your software that don't have the arbitrary restrictions you've decided to impose.

Comment: Never sell your software to customers you expect to pirate it from you...whatever anybody tells you on here there will always be ways to get around your own custom DRM, or a commercially provided one.

Comment: Also, what happens if your site goes down? Or you don't run it any more? Your software stops working? I wouldn't buy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a good option to use the webservice. But to make it work, you will have to make sure that the software is always connected to internet while it is invoked.

There are other offline options also available. here is the linke to a couple of them

http://www.smart-lock.com/

http://www.keylok.com/

They are keys which protect the execution unless the key is inserted in the machine.

There are further few more options available such as detecting the serial number of hard disk or identify the machine from mac address but they are not completely secure though. There are further issues such as change in hardware will cause the software stop working.

Comment: I want the locking system in my set up file. which will prevent software being installing.

Comment: You can use inno setup which is a configurable setup creator and also allows you to write pascal scripts to write an installation protection logic. I have been doing so from quite a while. Another option is to use nullsoft installer which provides same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The best way i can see for achieving this would be to create a key in the registry in the current user.

A sample code to do this would be:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

P.S. You should encrypt your key value or else it would be very easily hacked.

Comment: One can easily create a new key on any machine. This is in no way a secure option.

Comment: he can create an encrypted key, and decrypt it on the application level, i will edit my answer.

Comment: It becomes a static binding any how. I have cracked several such softwares to just experiment with security. Further, using web service is also not a good option as it can also be easily spoofed.